# How to replace a special character with an escaped version in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyodbc

I am trying to replace special characters in a string so that I can insert into DB using pyodbc.It seems to be erroring when I do to execute the query and not what I concat the string.

Fixed
Changed the query to this as suggested

```
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Decks (Name,Company,About,Printer,Artist,Notes,Collection,ReleaseYear,ProductionRun,Stock,Finish,CourtIllistration) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", name, company, about, printer, artist, notes, collection, release_year, production_run, card_stock, finish, court_illustration )
```

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 104, in 
cursor.execute(query)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 's'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
Press any key to continue . . .

Environment

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio community
- Python 3.8
- bs4 0.0.1
- beautifulsoup 4.9.3
- pyodbc 4.0.30

Example
company = "Murphy's Magic"

I tried

company = company.replace("'","\'")
The result was nothing changing.

company = company.replace("'","\\'")
result = "Murphy\\'s Magic"

I have also tried encapsulated the string with different quotes. As well as assigning the string to a variable first.  I can just replace the special characters with "" but would rather keep them.

Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from bs4 import Comment
import pyodbc as db
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client
import re
import copy

#Creating a db connection
conn = db.connect('''DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
                        SERVER=localhost;
                        DATABASE=FullStack;
                        PORT=1433;
                        UID=Decky;
                        PWD=halo;''')

#Getting the curser that will execute the inserts 
cursor = conn.cursor()

for i in range(6,50):
    name = "N/A"
    about = "N/A"
    company = "N/A"
    edition = "N/A"
    collection = "N/A"
    release_year = "N/A"
    production_run = "N/A"
    printer = "N/A"
    artist = "N/A"
    card_stock = "N/A"
    finish = "N/A"
    court_illustration = "N/A"
    notes = "N/A"

    # URl to web scrape from.
    page_url = "https://www.portfolio52.com/deck/"+str(i)+"/view"

    # opens the connection and downloads html page from url
    uClient = uReq(page_url)

    # parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
    # as if it were a json data type.
    page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
 
    for comments in page_soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment)):
        if "deck-page-header" in comments:
            whatINeed = comments
            break

    page_soup = soup(whatINeed, 'html.parser')

    deck_info_soup = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "deck-info"})

    #Getting the name of the deck
    name = deck_info_soup[0].select("h1")[0].text

    deck_main_info_soup = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "deck-main-info"}) 

    #Getting the about section
    about = deck_main_info_soup[0].getText()

    #Getting the other deck fields 
    deck_fields_soup = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "deck-fields"}) 
    #Getting the rest of the fields all stored in <p>
    fields = deck_fields_soup[0].select("p")
    for field in fields:
        if "COMPANY:" in field.text:
            company = field.text.replace("COMPANY:", "")
            company = company.replace("'","\'")
        if "EDITION:" in field.text:
            edition = field.text.replace("EDITION:", "")
        if "COLLECTION" in field.text:
            collection = field.text.replace("COLLECTION", "")
        if "RELEASE YEAR:" in field.text:
            release_year = field.text.replace("RELEASE YEAR:", "")
        if "PRODUCTION RUN:" in field.text:
            production_run = field.text.replace("PRODUCTION RUN:", "")
        if "PRINTER:" in field.text:
            printer = field.text.replace("PRINTER:", "")
        if "ARTIST:" in field.text:
            artist = field.text.replace("ARTIST:", "")
        if "CARD STOCK:" in field.text:
            card_stock = field.text.replace("CARD STOCK:", "")
        if "FINISH:" in field.text:
            finish = field.text.replace("FINISH:", "")
        if "COURT ILLUSTRATION:" in field.text:
            court_illustration = field.text.replace("COURT ILLUSTRATION:", "")

    query = '''INSERT INTO Decks (Name,Company,About,Printer,Artist,Notes,Collection,ReleaseYear,ProductionRun,Stock,Finish,CourtIllistration)
            VALUES(\''''+name+'''\',
                   \''''+company+'''\',
                   \''''+about+'''\',
                   \''''+printer+'''\',
                   \''''+artist+'''\',
                   \''''+notes+'''\',
                   \''''+collection+'''\',
                   \''''+release_year+'''\',
                   \''''+production_run+'''\',
                   \''''+card_stock+'''\',
                   \''''+finish+'''\',
                   \''''+court_illustration+'''\')'''

    # Commiting the insert to the db 
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    print(name)


#closing the connection to the DB and to the Uclient
conn.close()
uClient.close()
```

Comment: Could you also include the traceback of the error?

Comment: It's misspelled as `comapny`, is that just a typo in the post?

Comment: I fixed the typo but I was debugging and was looking at the result of the replace. So same issue still. Also added the traceback  Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is that you are embedding column values directly into your SQL command text. That is bad practice. If you use a proper *parameterized query* then you won't have to worry about escaping any special characters. A web search for "SQL injection" will provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From edit to question:*

Fixed

Changed the query to this as suggested

```
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Decks (Name,Company,About,Printer,Artist,Notes,Collection,ReleaseYear,ProductionRun,Stock,Finish,CourtIllistration) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", name, company, about, printer, artist, notes, collection, release_year, production_run, card_stock, finish, court_illustration )
```